# How can I bind a list of numbers in C# in CSV format to a controller-level property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, query-string

I have this URL:

```
https://api.example.com/copmare/data?entityType=car&ids=1,2,3
```

I want to bind that `1,2,3` CSV to a `List<int>` in my code.

I'm using this code, but it does not work:

```
public class CompareController : Controller
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
    public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

But it does not work and tells me that the value is not valid for that property.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried adding the parameters into your API action: `[FromQuery] string entityType, [FromQuery] List<int> ids`? `public IActionResult YourAction([FromQuery] string entityType, [FromQuery] List<int> ids)`

Comment: @YongShun, is it possible to add that `[FromQuery]` to `[BindProperty]`?

Comment: I tested your code and worked. Which ASP.NET Core version do you use?

Comment: @YongShun, I'm using ASP.NET Core latest LTS (7.0.14 at the current time I guess).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core's model binder handles the conversion of a simple type directly from a query string parameter to the corresponding type. But for collection types, the model binder doesn't directly convert comma-separated strings to List<int>. You can use a custom model binder to convert it List<int>.

Controller:

```
public class CompareController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("data")]
    public IActionResult GetData([FromQuery] string entityType, [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyModelBinder))] List<int> ids)
    {
          
        return Ok(new { EntityType = entityType, Ids = ids });
    }
}
```

MyModelbinder:

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            var values = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(values))
            {
                var ints = values.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(ints);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

When I send data:
[image]